# TYPO3: Pass multiple arguments to a partial from a fluid template

Tags: typo3, partial, fluid, extbase, typo3-flow

I have a fluid template, from where I call an often used snippet (called "partial"):

Template:

```
<f:render partial="fbLikeBox" arguments="{settings}"/>
```

Partial fbLikeBox.html:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/xxxxxxxx"></script>
<fb:like href="{settings.baseURL}/details/?guide_uid={audioguide.uid}">
</fb:like>
```

As you can see, I need both values from the {settings} and the {audioguide} array passed to the partial. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Starting with TYPO3 4.6, you could just use

```
<f:render partial="fbLikeBox" arguments="{_all}" />
```

The {_all} will simple make sure all variables currently available in your template, are available in the partial.

Comment: Cool solution, however occasionally I get the exception: `The argument "arguments" was registered with type "array", but is of type "object" in view helper`. This might happen when I call _nested partials_. Using below method works fine.

Comment: Also, with `{_all}` you might run into performance issues. If loading time is too long, try to reduce the number of arguments.

Comment: This is not an answer to to OP's question. While it might work for the OP, the answer from konsolenfreddy is correct

Answer (score 31):

you can use an array, like:

```
<f:render partial="fbLikeBox" arguments="{settings : settings, audioguide:audioguide}"/>
```

They're `key : value` pairs where the value defines the accessible name in your partial